How to enable AQE on databricks spark streaming for each batch
I am processing the daily data from checkpoint to checkpoint everyday by using for each batch in streaming way.
df.writeStream.format("delta")
        .option("checkpointLocation", "dbfs/loc")
        .foreachBatch(transform_and_upsert)
        .outputMode("update")
        .trigger(availableNow=True)
        .start()

Due to skewness I want to enable aqe and set skewJoin optimization true
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.skewJoin.enabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.adaptive.forceOptimizeSkewedJoin", "true")

However, when I checked the Spark UI settings, the value was set to false: spark.sql.adaptive.enabled = false.
I am using Databricks DBR 14.3.x-photon-scala2.12 with Photon enabled.
According to this https://www.databricks.com/blog/adaptive-query-execution-structured-streaming, AQE supports streaming for each batch query starting from DBR 13.2.

You need to configure the AQE settings in your Spark session.
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder \
.appName("Spark Streaming with AQE") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.enabled", "true") \
.config("spark.sql.adaptive.shuffle.targetPostShuffleInputSize", "134217728") \  
.getOrCreate()

This code enables AQE and applies a shuffle size configuration.
